# Simple description of circularities in Knuth original attribute grammar paper

Tags: formal-grammars

[Knuth's original attribute grammar paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.455.1434) (title: *Semantics of Context-Free Languages*) introduced three types of circularity. More specifically section "Testing for circularity" page 134-5 figures 3.1-3. I am wondering if it's possible someone would explain in simple terms the three types of circularities. I am very confused.

I think there should be either direct or indirect dependencies.

By direct, I mean

```
A.attr := B.attr
B.attr := A.attr
```

By indirect, I mean

```
A.attr := B.attr
B.attr := C.attr
... maybe more steps ...
C.attr := A.attr
```

Comment: It's important to understand that the problem is not finding a circularity in a particular evaluation. Given a dependency graph on a concrete parse, it's easy to figure out if there is a circularity. Knuth's algorithm determines whether *any* parse tree which might be generated by the grammar has a circular dependence.